# Need Help with Aligning Labels Below Each Bar in TikZ Bar Chart

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I am struggling with moving the labels {1, …, 6} in my bar chart. I would like to locate each label precisely at the center below each respective bar but I'm not sure how to do this.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{\textbf{Tid det tar för brustabletten att lösas upp i de olika vätskorna}}
\label{fig:experiment}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0,
    xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6},
    xticklabels={1,2,3,4,5,6},
    xlabel=Experiment,
    ylabel=Tid (s),
    bar width=0.5cm,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
    axis lines*=left,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    xticklabel style={text width=1.5cm,align=center}
]
    \addplot[fill=red!50] coordinates {(1,157)};
    \addplot[fill=blue!50] coordinates {(2,173)};
    \addplot[fill=green!50] coordinates {(3,150)};
    \addplot[fill=orange!50] coordinates {(4,134)};
    \addplot[fill=purple!50] coordinates {(5,80)};
    \addplot[fill=brown!50] coordinates {(6,123)};
    \legend{Kallt vatten, Kall läsk, Läsk utan kolsyra, Varm läsk utan kolsyra, Varmt vatten, Varm läsk}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Any help or advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated please.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set (default value of) `bar shift` to zero:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines*=left,
%
    ybar,
    bar width=6mm,
    bar shift=0mm,      % <---
    ymin=0,
    xtick={1,2,...,6},
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
%
    xlabel=Experiment,
    ylabel=Tid (s),
%
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
                  anchor=north, legend columns=3, font=\footnotesize,
                  cells={anchor=west},
                  /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=1em}},
]
    \addplot[fill=red!50]       coordinates {(1,157)};
    \addplot[fill=blue!50]      coordinates {(2,173)};
    \addplot[fill=green!50]     coordinates {(3,150)};
    \addplot[fill=orange!50]    coordinates {(4,134)};
    \addplot[fill=purple!50]    coordinates {(5, 80)};
    \addplot[fill=brown!50]     coordinates {(6,123)};
    \legend{Kallt vatten, Kall läsk, Läsk utan kolsyra, Varm läsk utan kolsyra, Varmt vatten, Varm läsk}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```